# Module not working in joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-module

problem is self made module not working- I make my self made module in Joomla 3.0. I made a **mod_products** folder here we created a file called **mod_products.php**.

**mod_products.php** - code

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once __DIR__ . '/helper.php';         
$value = modProductsHelper::getproducts( $params );
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_products', $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

and after it I made second file **helper.php** code -

```
class modProductsHelper{

    public static function getProducts( $params ){
          return 'Products';
    }

}
```

and third one is **default.php**

```
<?php      

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

if($value!='') { ?>

<ul style="margin-left: 0px;" class="clients-list slides-list slide-wrapper">
       <li class="slide">
            <div class="product-image"><img src="images/product3.png" width="181" height="177"></div>
       </li>       
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Then we install through administrator panel and gave a position to the **mod_products** module and display in **index.php** file like so:

```
<div class="grid_12 product_home">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" />
</div>
```

But it's not being displayed on the site. Does anyone have any idea why?

Edit:mod_products.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<extension type="module" version="3.0" client="site" method="upgrade"> 
    <name>mod_products</name> 
    <author>Joomla! Project</author> 
    <creationDate>July 2004</creationDate> 
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright> 
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license> 
    <authorEmail>admin@joomla.org</authorEmail> 
    <authorUrl>www.joomla.org</authorUrl> 
    <version>3.0.0</version> 
    <description>MOD_PRODUCTS_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <files> 
        <filename module="mod_products">mod_products.php</filename> 
        <folder>tmpl</folder> 
        <filename>helper.php</filename> 
        <filename>mod_products.xml</filename> 
    </files> 
    <config> 
    </config> 
</extension>
```

Comment: Did you create an XML file too?

Comment: yes i make mod_products.xml file

Comment: try `var_dump($value)` to see what the result is. Also try using `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';` instead. Yes, please show you XML code. If you want, you can send me the module so I can test and I'll send a fixed version back to you

Comment: ok but how i send you my module here we only paste code

Comment: dont worry, I'll replicate your module from the code you have provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I've created a small example for you. I think it might have been due to you calling the wrong module layout, not entirely sure.

Here is a link to download the module. Uninstall the current module you're using via the Joomla backend and install this:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/ucp3prv219430zl/mod_products.zip

Also, don't forget to assign the module to a menu item. That *might* have been the problem before

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems your problem is module name.In some places you have used mod_product and in other places mod_products Please make sure you use only one.I will suggest you to change

```
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_products', $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

to

```
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_product', $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

Also check that you have published the module and also test it for all pages.

Comment: but my folder name is mod_products

Comment: @PreetiBisht:Then you must change all mod_product instance to mod_products.like your module filename is mod_product.php it should be mod_products.php

Comment: sorry by mistake i wrote mod_product but its mod_products

Comment: ok,that's fine.Then problem is in you xml file.Could you paste that too?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="3.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
 <name>mod_products</name>
 <author>Joomla! Project</author>
 <creationDate>July 2004</creationDate>
 <copyright>Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright>
 <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
 <authorEmail>admin@joomla.org</authorEmail>
 <authorUrl>www.joomla.org</authorUrl>
 <version>3.0.0</version>
 <description>MOD_PRODUCTS_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>

Comment: <files>
  <filename module="mod_products">mod_products.php</filename>
  <folder>tmpl</folder>
  <filename>helper.php</filename>
  <filename>mod_products.xml</filename>
 </files>
 <config>
 </config>
</extension>

Comment: @PreetiBisht - no, the xml is fine

Comment: @PreetiBisht:Your code is working fine.I think you have not give it to the right position/menu or forget to publish.

Comment: thanks, i got it its a problem in administrator section pages was none